# Using variables created inside other job build inside on Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need to read some vars created inside another job. Easier to be explain with pseudo code:
my job:

```
{
build job:"create cluster" //this job will create some vars (cluster_name)
//used this var from my job
echo "${cluster_name}"
}
```

The best will be with declarative pipelines but I can always use script {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly in your `create cluster` job you need to put that variable into environment variable. You can do it this way

```
//create cluster Jenkinsfile
env.CLUSTER_NAME = cluster_name
```

Then in your upstream job you can receive that variable using a result of `build` step.

```
def result = build job: 'create cluster'
echo result.buildVariables.CLUSTER_NAME
```

Comment: Working perfect :)  is there a way to do that in declarative pipelines?

Comment: @Guel135 you can use [script {}](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) to include this code in declarative pipeline.

Comment: This I know it, but for make it cleaner, nevermind, thanks and now it is working